# How do you delete a matrix block in module/plugin assuming you have the matrix block id and entry

Tags: matrix

I have the channel entry to which the matrix block belongs and I have the ID of the block itself. Does anybody know the correct approach for deleting the matrix block on the entry?

Context: module (PHP) not template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Elements service](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-elements.html) to delete any element, including matrix blocks:

```php
use craft\elements\MatrixBlock;

/** @var craft\services\Elements $elementsService */
$elementsService = Craft::$app->getElements();

$myMatrixBlockId = 123;

// delete a matrix block directly
$matrixBlock = MatrixBlock::find()->id($myMatrixBlockId)->one();
$elementsService->deleteElement($matrixBlock, false);

// delete a matrix block by ID
$elementsService->deleteElementById($myMatrixBlockId, null, null, false);
```

The second argument to `deleteElement` (and the fourth argument to `deleteElementById`) controls if you want a hard delete (`true`) or a soft-delete (`false`). A hard delete removes the block from the database completely, while a soft delete keeps it in the database and only marks it as deleted, allowing it to be restored.

- [craft\services\Elements::deleteElement()](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-elements.html#method-deleteelement)
- [craft\services\Elements::deleteElementById()](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-elements.html#method-deleteelementbyid)

Comment: Heroic answer, thank you very much!